# If $E$ is a splitting field over $F$ for $f,g \in F[x]$, then $f$ is separable over $F$ iff $g$ is separable over $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $F \subseteq E$ be a splitting field over $F$ both for $f \in F[x]$ and for $g \in F[x]$. I claim that $f$ is separable over $F$ iff $g$ is separable over $F$.

Suppose that $f$ is separable over $F$, that is each irreducible factor of $f$ in $F[x]$ has distinct roots. Also, $f(x)=a\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\alpha_i)$ and $g(x)=b\prod_{i=1}^m(x-\beta_i)$ in $E[x]$. I need to show that each irreducible factor of $g$ in $F[x]$ has distinct roots in order to $g$ is separable over $F$.

I need some help. How to prove this assertion ?

Comment: Do you mean the $E$ is the splitting field for $f$ and that $E$ is the splitting field for $g$ or that $E$ is the smallest field in which both $f,g$ split? I.e. Do we have $E=K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)=K(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m)$ or do we have $E=K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m)?$

Comment: I mean E is splitting field over F both for f and for g

Comment: i.e. $E=F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)=F(\beta_1,...,\beta_n)$.

Comment: I maybe misunderstanding this but I think this statement is false if f and g are not irreducible over F. For example take $g(x) = f^2(x)$. Perhaps your definition of separable includes irreducible?

Comment: Usually, separable means the irreducible factors are separable

Answer (score 0):

Since E is a splitting field of $f$ and $g$, assuming $f$ is separable, you have that $E|F$ is a Galois extension, thus in particular separable, so $g$ is separable.

You can prove that the following statemant holds:

Given a finite extension $E|F$ the following are equivalent:
1. $E|F$ is Galois
2. $E$ is a splitting field for a separable polynomial $0\ne f \in F[x]$

The interesting implication is 2 -> 1. To prove it you have to prove, or assume, these two:

1. If $E$ is a splitting field of a polynomial $f \ne 0$ in $F[x]$ and all roots are distinct, then $|Gal(E|F)| = [E:F]$
2. For a finite extension $E|F$ they are equivalent, being $G=Gal(E|F)$:

   - $E|F$ is Galois
   - $F = Fix(G)$

Comment: Just because $E$ is a separable extension, how do you know $g$ is separable? Don't we have to assume $g$ is irreducible for this to follow?

Comment: I always read the definition of separability as: a polynomial $h \in F[x]$ is separable over $F$ iff each of its irreducible factors has distinct roots in a splitting field for $h$ @CuriousKid7